# How to make my slider do something at every specified pixel interval?

Tags: javascript

I have a nice working slider script (no libraries used). I need a math concept that would allow the slider to perform a callback on a specified pixel interval. So for example, my slider is 300px wide, and I specify the interval=10, then when the user slides the handle, the callback should happen at pixel positions 10,20,30,40 and so on. If the interval=3 then the callback should happen at pixel positions 3,6,9,12...etc. 
It's the math formula that I am looking for specifically.
Any help would be appreciated.

Pat

Comment: Really hard to answer without seeing any code, but I imagine you would have to pre-define the slider points before rendering, and then compare the slider's position to them while moving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So say you have the variables:

```
var width = 300;   // px
var interval = 10; // px
var pos; // current position
```

And then you should do:

```
if ( pos % interval === 0 ) 
  // do stuff
```

This is called `modulus operator` which returns the remainder of dividing `left_var` by `right_var`. If the `remainder` is `0` your check will return `true`, and so you do the callback (exactly at pixel 10, 20, 30, 40, etc.).

But please note that it's very naive to think that you will be able to handle every pixel change... What I'd rather do is to examine if the slider has entered to a given segment.

```
var segment = 1;
```

Then after the state of the slider changes you check for position like this:

```
if ( Math.floor( pos / interval ) === segment ) {
  // do stuff because the slider
  // has entered a new segment
  // ...
  segment++;
}
```

If the slider moves backwards and you want to fire the events accordingly just decrement the segment instead of incrementing.

Comment: Thank you for your good advice on this issue. Both methods work well. You indicated that you would prefer the segment method. The only thing I should probably do differently is instead of using math.floor, use a n|0 or n|n bit shift for better speed, correct?